# difference between permission on the directory

Tags: unix, symfony, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

I have the following problem about permission on the directory.
Actually I installed `symphony2.0` and I get the following error:

```
RuntimeException: Unable to write in the cache directory   
(/Users/someUser/Sites/someApp/app/cache/dev)
```

if I list the directory I get

```
ll /Users/someUser/Sites/someApp/app/cache
(1)
drwxr-xr-x someUser
```

I have another installation which works and for which the permissions are

```
(2)
drwxr-xr-x+ someUser
```

So my question is how can I obtain (2) ?
I run the following command (3) to obtain (1) but I have no idea how to obtain (2).

```
(3)
sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

---

P.S.:
the difference about (1) and (2) is just an `+` at the end.

Comment: the + sign means it is an ACL (Access Control List)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

1) Using ACL on a system that supports chmod +a

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*

$ sudo chmod +a "www-data allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
$ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

2) Using Acl on a system that does not support chmod +a

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs

$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Anyway in my case `ls- l` is equivalent to `ls`. anyway the owner is the same. I updated my question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `+` sign at the end of the permissions indicates the presence of an ACL list, an extension to *nix's normal permissions. You can print this out using `ls -lZ`. You can then `setfacl` to set them.